# moving binary database folder is causing issues with innodb tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

so I have a mix of myisam and innodb tables on a database. (its a pretty big db 30gb)
I copied the folder of the database from one server to the next `/var/lib/mysql/databasename`
well the myisam tables are opening The innodb tables are listed but when I click on any of them on the left tab (phpmyadmin) I get this error: `#1146 - Table 'databasename.users' doesn't exist`
this would be for the users table. Other innodb tables are having the same issue.
I would like to know how to remedy this issue. 
I logged in to mysql directly through ssh as root, when I do : `SHOW TABLES;`
the table users and the other innodb tables are all listed. When I do `SHOW COLUMNS FROM users;`
I get :

```
mysql> show columns from article;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sitecontent.article' doesn't exist
```

any ideas please ? (issue resides in innodb tables only!)

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [dba.Se]

Comment: i think they are not fully copied yet, drop and recreate database may helps you or you didn't copied the both structure and their contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL returns `Table 'sitecontent.article' doesn't exist` that means that InnoDB can't find any records in the dictionary for table `sitecontent.article`. That mean ibdata1 (where InnoDB dictionary is stored) is foreign to your database. It must have been lost somewhere one the way to the new server.

Comment: I am double checking, i will copy it again. Thank You !